# Windows explorer thumbnails stopped generating for Canon Raw (.cr2) files only, except intermittently

Tags: windows-7, thumbnails, raw

Updating the question because I know more about the cause of the issue, but still don't know how to solve it.

Currently I can see thumbnails for **some** CR2 files in windows explorer. Maybe only 1-5% of all of them. I can force windows to generate a thumbnail for any specific thumbnail (by repeatedly clicking it and pressing F5 to refresh its folder). Therefore, I don't think the problem is that I lack an app that can read and create CR2 thumbnails. I definitely have an app that can do this (FastPictureViewer). I have hundreds of thumbnails successfully generated. The problem is that I have tens of thousands of RAW files.

Just FYI, Canon's own Raw Codec, as well as Microsoft's Camera Codec Pack, as well as SageThumbs, are all based on an older version of the CR2 format so they don't work to make thumbnails for RAW files created by a newer camera, in my case a Rebel T5.

I am 99% convinced the problem is because Windows has a limit to the size of the thumbnail cache. A registry entry exists to increase this limit:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\
Create a new key called Max Cached Icons and give it a value that represents the size of if the icon cache, i.e. 4096 for 4 megs.

Here's where it gets muddy - I have gotten much conflicting info about this key.

• Some say this key should be of the type "string"
• Some say it should be of the type "Dword"
• One user suggests it should be "Qword" on a 64 bit system.
• One user says it used to be "String" but this is considered unorthodox to control with a string value, and should be a dword, and one of microsoft's updates for windows7 changes it to the more approprite dword type.
• I've seen the key both with and without spaces (e.g. MaxCachedIcons) Without is more typical for a registry key but several users go out of their way to say "yes, include the spaces even though that's unusual".

Additionally - there is no single file for the thumbnail cache, there are multiple files for the multiple icon sizes. These live in C:\Users[Username]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer and are named

thumbcache_32.db
thumbcache_96.db
thumbcache_256.db
thumbcache_1024.db

So it's unclear if this setting limits the size of all 4 files together, or allows each of these 4 files to grow to the limit you set.

After deleting these and allowing windows to rebuild them, I either don't have the registry key in the correct format (though I experimented with many formats), or Windows has a hard limit on the thumbnail cache that can't be exceeded regardless of the size in the registry key. I tried 2048, 4096, 8192. Weirdly, the files at one point wouldn't go beyond 3148 kb (3 megs). Currently they are stuck at 4096 but the registry key is set for 8192. I have never seen any of these files grow beyond 4096.

I know I am on the right track because if I delete them and then start forcing thumbnails to generate using the method described earlier, the size of the icon database list grows (thumbcache_idx.db) but the other .db files refuse to grow any more. This link describes how the thumbnails all work: http://www.identatron.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/Cyberforensics-2011.pdf

And these files definitely control the CR2 thumbnails because I can use a small app called thumbcacheviewer (or thumbcache_viewer) to open the DB files and view the thumbnails inside of them, and they are my CR2 thumbnails.

So right now, I am convinced I have hit the limit of thumbnails in windows. Now it's just a matter of... if I enter this registry key in a different way, can I bypass the limit? Or is it just set in stone?

Comment: Did you try [clearing the thumbnail cache](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/clear-thumbnail-cache-windows-7-vista/)? Do you get the same issue if you use a different account?

Comment: @and31415 yes cleared thumbnail cache, yes same issue in another account. Also tried booting in safe mode and same issue.

Comment: Are there any files in the `C:\Windows\Minidump` folder? Dump files could shed more light on the BSOD. If you haven't already, check the file system health by running this command from an [elevated command prompt](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/command-prompt-faq#1TC=windows-7): `chkdsk %systemdrive% /r` When done, check the system integrity by running the following command: `sfc /scannow`

Comment: @and31415 hi, thanks for the suggestions. No minidump folder. SFC found a corrupted file and fixed it. I then ran chkdsk and no errors found. 

I did find a bunch of errors under event viewer around the time it probably happened. They haven't returned since then. 

I copied just these errors to a text file but it came out with xml, kind of a pain to read? https://www.dropbox.com/s/fzbdrj83nsrjygz/creedorofl_error_log.txt

Comment: Run the `sfc` command again and ensure there are no issues. Where are your `.cr2` files stored, exactly? Do you get the same issue if you copy them to an external drive/media? Also, is the `C:\Windows\LiveKernelReports` folder empty? I checked those errors, but I guess they're unrelated as they refer to network services.

Comment: @and31415 Ran SFC again, comes back 100% clean. I have CR2 files spread across 2 internal hard drives, and one external USB drive. The issue happens in all of them. 

I think we're barking up the wrong tree. I have read windows has some arbitrary limit on thumbnails. One guy posts that it stops caching after about 7,500 of them. I unfortunately do have more than that (by far). So if this limit cannot be broken then I dunno what to do short of maybe offloading them to another drive, clearing cache, and disconnecting that drive.

Comment: The `Max Cached Icons` (spaces needed) registry value should be of type `REG_SZ` (the string is converted to an integer number internally). By default, the value is `500`, and the valid range is `100-65535`. What the value does is put an upper limit to the amount of icons stored in the icon database (i.e. `%LocalAppData%\IconCache.db`) The actual code is located inside the `shell32.dll` library. As a side note, if you have a `REG_DWORD` value in a 32-bit system, it will still be a `REG_DWORD` value in a 64-bit system and *not* a `REG_QWORD`. Simply put, it's unrelated to thumbnails.

Comment: The thumbnails are handled by specific functions which are found inside `thumbcache.dll`. [Here's a post](http://bit.ly/Vut5Fn) which lists some (undocumented) registry values you might want to experiment with. This article might be useful, too: [Vista thumbcache](http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Vista_thumbcache)

Comment: The undocumented registry entries look promising. But I'm not sure of the format. All DWORDs? I can't seem to find anyone confirming that they work, I just now tried boosting the value for HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ThumbnailCache\MaxCacheFileSize256 to 999999999 and letting it truncate to the normal maximum (65,535 I think). But when I revisit folders that are missing thumbnails, no change.

Comment: Usually, numeric values are stored as `REG_DWORD` (32-bit) in the registry. And yes, all `MaxCacheFileSize*` values should be `REG_DWORD`. Keep in mind that those settings are only read once the cache gets initialized, so you should close all programs, change the values, clear the cache, and log off afterwards. Either way, I guess the value is related to the amount of cached items for each thumbnail size (it should be `50` by default). So you might try using a smaller value, e.g. `100` for each setting - from `MaxCacheFileSize32` to `MaxCacheFileSize1024`.

Answer (score 1):

According to the error log that you posted, the problem dates from august 10,
which is recent enough to rollback Windows to a system restore point
that dates to before that time. Ensure first that all the software you had at that time
is installed in the same folders as before. This will also create a new system restore point
from now, that you can rollback to in case you wish to undo the first rollback.
I would also take before starting a disk image backup of the system drive just in case.

If this doesn't work,
I suggest uninstalling the Camera Codec Pack and FastPictureViewer using [Revo Uninstaller Freeware](http://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html).
Then reboot and install instead the free [SageThumbs](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sagethumbs/?source=typ_redirect). If it doesn't work, uninstall it from the Control Panel
Programs and Features.

If nothing works, I suggest buying the FastPictureViewer Codec Pack ($9.99)
and asking for support if the problem still occurs.

---

In case you have run into the icon disk size limit :

Icons are cached in the iconcache.db file whose size is limited by default to
more or less 500KB.
Here is how to increase this limit :

1. Run regedit and navigate to the key
   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer`
2. If you do not see on the right pane an entry named **Max Cached Icons**,
   right-click on an empty area, then click on **New** and on **String Value**,
   type `Max Cached Icons` and press Enter.
3. Double-click on **Max Cached Icons** to modify it.
4. Click on **Decimal**
5. Type a number for how many kilobytes (KB) you want the maximum icon cache size,
   for example 8192 for 8 MB.
6. Click on OK

For more detail see the article [Windows 7: Icon Cache Size - Change in Windows](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/268478-icon-cache-size-change-windows.html).

You might also need to [rebuild the Icon Cache](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/49819-icon-cache-rebuild.html) and reboot for this to take effect.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestions. So far I tried a system restore which happens to offer only as far back as the morning of August 10th. I clicked "show more restore points" but got nothing. I ran the earliest restore point available and after the reboot I get "System Restore did not complete successfully" etc. It references failing to replace the file "C:\Windows" which is a lil vague. I tried a different restore point with the same result. 

I tried Revo Uninstalled, killed all traces of FastPictureViewer, but admit I forgot about CCP. In any case all thumbs for CR2s disappeared.

Comment: Afterwards, I installed Sagethumbs. It slightly changed the CR2 icon but failed to replace it with a thumbnail. It labels the CR2 file as an "EOS 1D Mark II" raw file which unfortunately is a camera from like 2006. So I don't think it's up to date on canon raws. 

Any other thoughts? Uninstall CCP just to be safe or does that seem like a dead end?

Comment: I suggest uninstalling every related product except the software you are testing. Analysis: Evidently something changed on your computer. The likely assumption is that this was done by Windows Update, and then a possible conclusion is that perhaps the old FastPictureViewer is no longer compatible with Explorer. (I wonder if the problem is only with .rc2 files?) A newer version could possibly fix it. At least as a client of the latest version you could ask for support. But it's your $9.99; and my analysis might be in error.

Comment: I think fastpicture viewer is working fine because many CR2 thumbnails do show up. It's just that we're talking only 1% or 2% of all the CR2 files on my system. I'm wondering if it's this windows thumbnail limit I've read about while googling. One user claims windows stops caching thumbnails after about 7,500 of them.

Comment: It's possible if you have very many image files. I have added above how to increase that limit.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I checked out that reg. key and found lots of google results about it. I got conflicting reports on what format the reg. key should be in. I completely redid my original post... if you have the time maybe you could check it out.

Comment: My `thumbcache_*.db` seemed to be limited to 1MB and I don't have `Max Cached Icons`. If you have reached 4MB (seems like the correct limit) then you have already found the good combination, but it seems even this is not enough? Maybe you should use smaller icons. There is a guy [that claims](http://www.experts-exchange.com/OS/Microsoft_Operating_Systems/A_2574-IconCache-Max-Cached-Icons-DataType-Reverting-Incorrectly-from-STRING-to-DWORD-SOLUTION.html) that a bug in Windows causes the conversion STRING to DWORD. His solution was a startup script.

Comment: You could try this script for 8192 (8MB).