# Windows 10 won't automatically generate thumbnails for .CR2 RAW files but will generate for CR3 as normal

Tags: windows-explorer, images, thumbnails, thumbnail-generator

My Windows 10 machine has stopped generating thumbnails of Canon RAW CR2 files but will generate CR3 thumbnails as would be expected behaviour. I am able to generate them using a thumbnail generating programme, but they don't remain in the cache forever (I haven't been able to determine how long).

In a folder with mixed CR3 and CR2 files it will generate CR3 thumbnails normally but ignore CR2 ones even after it was generated for all the CR3 files. It's able to open CR2 files and view them normally, so I don't believe it's an issue with the codec at all, because it's only native thumbnail generation that's the issue.

I've tried reinstalling Raw Image Extension to no effect, and my Windows 10 version is 22H2 (OS Build 19045.2728)

EDIT: For anyone reading this with a similar problem, I found a workaround if not an actual solution - I installed FastPictureViewer. For some reason, that resolves the issue, albeit it doesn't actually address why Windows wasn't doing it in the first place.

Comment: What version of Windows are you running exactly?  You can use `winver` to determine that exact version and build.  Saying your installation is "fully updated" tells us very little due to the number of versions of Windows 10 that are fully supported..  It might not be important but I have seen weirder things be important.  What is the value of `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Max Cached Icons` and what are the size of these files?

Comment: I've updated to include the correct version, although it's been a problem for probably over a year anyway across multiple versions. 

I have no key for Max Cached Icons apparently. However, the CR2 files are generally smaller than the CR3 files anyway.

Comment: [Try creating it](https://superuser.com/questions/795032/windows-explorer-thumbnails-stopped-generating-for-canon-raw-cr2-files-only) and set it to a size greater than the largest file you have as a test. Do you have [this](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/raw-image-extension/9NCTDW2W1BH8?hl=en-us&gl=us) installed? Yes; The description mentions CR3 but I suspect it also supports CR2.  Besides at this point diagnostic information is helpful.

Comment: I've tried that method, no success. I've had that installed for a long time, and tried reinstalling as well.

Comment: Plus, I'm not convinced that's the issue anyway as it's continually generating new CR3 thumbnails anyway,

Comment: For anyone reading this with a similar problem, I found a workaround if not an actual solution - I installed FastPictureViewer. For some reason, that resolves the issue, albeit it doesn't actually address why Windows wasn't doing it in the first place.

Comment: Just to make sure: Those CR2 raws _do_ have an embedded thumbnail, right? Because that’s what Explorer (might) show. It will not attempt to deal with the actual raw image data.